# Duplicate Key error when I call form.Show() in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, debugging, key

I am having a problem that I cannot debug.

I have a form that when I press in a button its open an other form like this:

```
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.Close()
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.Text = pPageHeader
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.kerenGUID = KodKeren
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.TaarichNechonut = Taarich
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.SugHitpalgut = MisHitpalgut
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.KodKvutzatHitpalgut = cm.Current("Kod").ToString
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim_Perut.Show()
```

It does all the Load of the new form correctly and after it finish and will do the Show if fail.

the message Exception I get is:
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'kod'  Key being added: 'kod'

I have no idea about which list/dictionary its talking about,
I looked at the details of the exception and I see this:

```
**System.ArgumentException =** {"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'kod'  Key being added: 'kod'"}

**Data =** {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} 

**Values =**  {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}

**Keys =** {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}

**Source:** "mscorlib"

**StackTrace =**    at System.Collections.SortedList.Add(Object key, Object value)    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridColumnDescriptorCollection.EnsureSortedList()
at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridColumnDescriptorCollection.Find(String
name)    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridColumnDescriptorCollection.get_Item(String
name)    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridTableDescriptor.EnsureRecordRowColumns()
at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridTableDescriptor.get_RecordRowColumns()
at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridTableDescriptor.GetColumnSetColCount()
at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridTableModelVolatileData.get_ColCount()
at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridModel.get_ColCount()    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridScroll.GetMaxColScrollPosition()   
at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridScroll.ColIndexToScrollPosition(Int32
colIndex)    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridScroll.GetNextColIndex(Int32&
colIndex, Boolean skipFirstHidden)    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridScroll.GetNextColIndex(Int32
colIndex, Boolean skipFirstHidden)    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridControlBase.GetFirstScrollableCol()
at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridControlBase.Initialize()    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridTableControl.Initialize() 
at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridGroupingControl.OptimizeLoadTime()
at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridGroupingControl.f_Load(Object
sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)   
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)   
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Office2007Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&
m)    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntCreateWindowEx(Int32
dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style,
Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent,
HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)    at
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(Int32
dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style,
Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent,
HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)    at
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()    at
System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()    at
System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)    at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()    at
Elad.BakaratNeemanut.UI.wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim.btnPerut_Click(Object
sender, EventArgs e) in
C:\WorkingFolder\NeemanutRoot\NeemanutWcfTest\UI\BakarotShotfot\wfrmBkrShotefHitpalgutNechasim.vb:line
242

**IsVurtual =** true

**FullQualifieldName** = "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"

**Module =** {System.Reflection.Module}
```

Any suggestions how to find what its the error and fix it?

Comment: You are showing no code. We can't help you without your relevant code.

Comment: comment out the line where you assign from cm.Current("Kod").ToString, see what happens.

Comment: It is an issue with the Syncfusion grid control.  If you can't debug the problem with the vendor provided source code then you are much more likely to find help at their support forums.

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorry for the inconvenience as I marked in the Answer the problem was with my grid.
because it didn't tell me where the error was I couldn't find it, but later I understood where the word "kod" was coming from.

Thank you very much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Ok People dont worry,

in the new form I was filling a grid, and there where 2 columns with the same name: "kod"

so that was the problem.

thanks any way.
Best regards!